# Symfony: pass parameter to Ajax url

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, twig

I am trying to figure out how to enable/disable user with checkbox without page reload.

*index.html.twig*

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>UserName</th>
      <th>Enabled</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   {% for user in users %}
     <td><a href="{{ path('user_show', {'id': user.id}) }}">
          {{ user.username }}</a>
     </td>
     <td><input id="user_enable_{{ user.id }}" onclick="enabledChange({{ user.id }})" 
     type="checkbox" {% if user.enabled %}checked{% endif %}/>
     </td>
   {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
var changePath = {{ path('user_enable_change', {'id': user.id}) }};

function enabledChange(id)
{
    var value = $(this).val();
    console.log('value: ' + value);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: changePath,
        async: true,
        data: { },
        success: function () {
            console.log('success');
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

*UserController*

```
 /**
 * @Route("/enable/{id}", name="user_enable_change")
 */
public function userDisableAction(User $user) {

    if($user->isEnabled()){
        $user->setEnabled(false);
    }else {
        $user->setEnabled(true);
    }

    try {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
    }
    catch(\Exception $e) {
        return new JsonResponse('error');
    }

    return new JsonResponse('success');

}
```

**Question**

How can I set corresponding user id to enabledChange function and change checked state depending on user state?

Comment: What problem are you facing with current code?

Comment: @alokpatel I have error: 'Variable "user" does not exist in @Admin/UserPanel/index.html.twig' because I am setting parameter user.id to changePath outside of {% for user in users %}

Comment: You've to define this inside `var changePath` function and used passed parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add quotes to your variables, and pass `changePath` as an argument:

```
onclick="enabledChange('{{ user.id }}', '{{ path('user_enable_change', {'id': user.id}) }}')"
```

then:

```
function enabledChange(id, changePath) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    console.log('value: ' + value);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: changePath,
        async: true,
        data: { },
        success: function () {
            console.log('success');
        }
    });
}
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Another clean way of doing this is by passing parameters and routes via data attributes and accessing the button by class. In my example I had to increase product quantity without refreshing:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-info increase"
data-id="{{ p.id }}"
data-url="{{ path('cart_add', {'pid': p.id}) }}">
Increase qty
</button>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".increase").click(function (e) {
        var value = $(this).data('id');
        console.log('value: ' + value);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(this).data('url'),
            async: true,
            data: {},
            success: function () {
                console.log('success increment');
            }
        });
    });
});
```